# What is the purpose of the class meta in Django?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

For what purpose is the **`class Meta:`** used in the class inside the Django [serializers.py](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) file?

Comment: it tells it the model to use and what fields to serialize ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Only the field can be displayed in the meta class

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've seen a lot written in the meta class, you just talked about the field itself

Comment: @joranBeasley Class meta is used for this reason only

Comment: its used for all the things @ https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer ... just read the docs ... it defines recursion depth and readonly attributes etc ... see all the Setting XXXX sections

Comment: It serves the same point as using a `Meta` class object inside a Django model class, or a form class, etc. It’s a standard pattern to attach configuration (metadata) to a set of fields that make up the model, form, or in this case, serializer.

Answer (score 6):

> Serializer classes can also include reusable validators that are
>   applied to the complete set of field data. These validators are
>   included by declaring them on an inner Meta class. 
>  Also when
>   you are defining a serializer then meta tags will help the serializer
>   to bind that object in the specified format

Below are some of the examples :

#### While validating request data in specified format:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    room_number = serializers.IntegerField(choices=[101, 102, 103, 201])
    date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        # Each room only has one event per day.
        validators = UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=Event.objects.all(),
            fields=['room_number', 'date']
        )
```

#### While getting data from db

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
```

More you can read [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

Answer (score 1):

The Meta class can be used to define various things about the model such as the permissions, database name, singular and plural names

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32623401)